# How to select or give style to all the child under the parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have 1 parent and 3 childs, for example:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="small-box-1">Small box 1</div>
    <div class="main-content">Main content</div>
</div>
```

I need to select all the child for background: red, without affecting the parent.
Normally I can just select the child class with something like:

```
.header, .small-box-1, .main-content{background: red}
```

In sass, I can use something like this:

```
& > * {background: red}
```

So it selects all the child under the parent.

I'm wondering if we can do that just using css? so I don't need to repeat the classes to define the `background: red`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASS is just a CSS pre-processor so everything you write in SASS will eventually be compiled to CSS.

With that said, if you do this in SASS:

```
.container {
  & > * {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

it will be converted to this CSS code:

```
.container > * {
  background: red;
}
```

So you should be able to use that CSS code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try somethings like this :

```css
/* Select all direct child "div" of the parent ".container" */

.container > div
{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

should try something like this:

```
div.container > div {
  background-color: red;
}
```